# Drag and drop image onto another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to do the following on a web page -

1. Have a large image (for example, a map) in the center.
2. Have several smaller images (for example, flags) in the side.
3. Allow a user to drag and drop the smaller images into the large image (Eg : Placing the flags onto the right country on the map).
4. Save the image ALONG with the smaller images superimposed on it.

I am very new to this concept, and I have no idea where to start (I'm not even sure if this is possible!). I am not looking to be spoonfed with code, just a few pointers in the right direction (and what language would be best for this!) would be absolutely great!

Note : I have tagged only the suggested tags, if anyone has any clue as to what language this would run well in, please do edit and add that tag, or let me know!

Comment: jquery will be helpful for drag n drop. There are some tutorials and demo examples available here: [jqueryui](https://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: @Sainath Krishnan I like your attitude, many people ask for a simple workout while you just want a direction. From my humble point of view, I'd suggest the following 2 ways: 1. Keep your large image unchanged (if it is repeated everywhere) and put the marker/flag in a positioned div where you can pass the position parameters (left/top) to the div and display it in the correct area in the output. 2. If you do have to merge the images into a new file you can use PHP GD library, it is widely used and well documented. Personally prefer option 1.

Comment: @Godinall Thank you! Option 1 is so simple yet so brilliant! Would never have though of it! I'll definitely give this a read and try it out.

My purpose is sort of simple. Lets say for example I have several logos that I want to put on a scarf/shirt/something, I want the users to be able to pick which logo they want at which position, and then when they save, the "order" gets saved in the database. Something along those lines :)

Thank you, I will definitely try what you said!

Comment: @Sainath Krishnan you are welcome, in your case I'd say option one is optimised. And I'd personally recommend you have several predefined positions such as top left/top right/bottom left/bottom right/centre. I understand you want to give your customer as much freestyle as possible but in the real world people would put them in some certain spots also your logo/design looks better in the right place. Anyway, you call, and if you go this approach, you can use relative % position. Say your T-shirt as base point, you can set logo 10% from left and 50% from top etc., this will make things easier.